# “You mentioned that you want” vs. “You had mentioned that you wanted”

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

How to say it in a right way and why?
 1. In your advertisement, you had mentioned that you wanted to know about...
 2. In your advertisement, you mentioned that you want to know about...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the person who mentioned their wish/desire, really had it at the moment of mentioning it, at least *not after* that moment. So it would be natural for the tenses to coincide:

> In your advertisement, you *mentioned* that you *wanted* to know about...

Or in case of some active advertisement:

> In your advertisement, you *mention* that you *want* to know about...